# pip and virtualenv installing parts of django in the wrong place

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I have been using virtualenv for a few weeks now without any problems until today. Using pip to install my env using -r requirements.txt, it is installing part of Django (v1.5) in the wrong place. Instead of putting the entire source into:

```
env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/
```

it is putting parts of conf/ and contrib/ at:

```
env/django/
```

Of course, parts of Django like the admin page would not work. When I moved these two dirs into the correct location, everything works fine, and there was no duplication of files. I also tried deleting the entire env directory and starting all over with the same result.

Any ideas as to why virtualenv & pip are splitting off parts of django into the wrong place (and how to fix it)?

Comment: Try to run `which pip` and `which python` to make sure that you use the right environment.

Answer (score 10):

Just met the same issue in our box too. fixed it by deleting this directory

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/pip
```

path may differ by OS, check this link to find your pip cache directory https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#caching

The reason is we have a corrupted cache of django in the box somehow, I found this by adding -v parameter when you install django to see the verbose output:

```
pip install -v django==1.5
```

in our case, it's just installed without downloading anything. then i added --no-cache-dir to install a clean one:

```
pip install -v django==1.5 --no-cache-dir
```

it works this time, there is no conf and contrib folder in the root of virtualenv, instead the files stay in site-packages which is we expected. and after we remove ~/.cache/pip, it also works fine with pip install django==1.5

Comment: `pip install django==1.5 --no-cache-dir` works fine for me — all files stayed in site-packages/django folder as expected

Comment: Thanks for that! I have spent too much time this week trying to workaround a bug this was causing.

Comment: That also works for django 1.3.1 ! I did a forced reinstall with --force-reinstall

Comment: `pip install django==1.3.7 --no-binary django --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall` for pip 19.2.3 in 2019 - how could this been running so long on django 1.3!!?

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to the top of requirements.txt:

```
--no-binary Django
```

(from https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2823)

Comment: I found that I needed to combine --no-cache-dir and --no-binary Django for this to work.