# AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute '_info'

Tags: python, django

I am working on a `Django` project and this error arises when I try to run any management commands such as:
`python manage.py validate --settings ord.settings.development`, `python manage.py syncdb --settings ord.settings.development`. The project uses `Django 1.5` The error is: `AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute '_info'`. No other output is given.

The project base settings file is: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5c0fede63b2724d7880b

The development settings: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f60b90dcf573b0a7b920

I have replaced sensitive settings with `x`

Any idea what could be wrong?

Some extra info, when i comment out the `LANGUAGE_CODE` settings, some commands like `validate`, `runserver`, `shell` run fine but `syncdb` and `migrate` fail with error: `DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`

Traceback: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bc3364ae5ba511566871

Comment: Please give the full traceback so we can tell what's actually causing the error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman there is no other output. When I run the management command, there is just one line of output: `'Nonetype' object has no attribute '_info'`

Comment: You have to run it with the `--traceback` option.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist i have added the traceback. Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Had the same issue,

Please follow the steps:

1. go to `django/utils/translation/trans_real.py`
2. search for `res = _translation(globalpath)`
3. Add the following:

   ```
   if res is None:
       return gettext_module.NullTranslations()
   ```

source: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18192

Comment: this will drop translation, if not found...only fighting symptoms. but agree, works ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem with a new installation on ubuntu 14.04.
After lots of digging - thought I should share my finding:
We are using django 1.5 and had the same error. It appears that the django installation was missing the folder django/conf/locale/en/**LC_MESSAGES**

Solution was to install latest version "pip install django==1.5.12"

Comment: Wow, thanks a ton! Not sure how it's related to 14.04, but I had Django 1.3. Copying LC_MESSAGES helped

Answer (score 4):

I have been getting this error with a virtualenv setup.

I noticed that pip was installing some parts of Django in the wrong place in my virtualenv - it was being installed in the top level folder of the virtualenv instead of in lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Anyway, I followed the advice on this answer, which involves clearing a corrupted pip cache:

[pip and virtualenv installing parts of django in the wrong place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017306/pip-and-virtualenv-installing-parts-of-django-in-the-wrong-place)

After that Django installed to the correct location and the error was gone.