# Django {% trans %} tag not displaying any text

Tags: django, translation

None of the {% trans %} tags in my templates show anything besides the msgid given to it. I am able to create the .po file correctly with makemessages and compile it successfully with compilemessages but when I run the server and bring up a page it doesn't show either language's translation, just the msgid.

For example:

```
{% trans "about-me-text" %}
```

This only displays "about-me-text" on the page instead of either the English or French translation.

My settings:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/path/to/project/locale',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en','English'),
    ('fr','French'),
)
```

This project is Django 1.3.1 and Python 2.7

Edit:

My .po file generated for about-me-text

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2017-06-28 12:48-0700\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: .\templates\about_me.html.py:8
msgid "about-me-text"
msgstr "This is the about me block"
```

about_me template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
    <article class="wrapped">
        <h2>{% trans "About Me" %}</h2>
        <div class="divider"></div>
            {% trans "about-me-text" %}
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

View:

```
def about_me(request):
    return render_to_response('about_me.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Is "about-me-text" meant to be a variable? Right now it is correct  - the text to display is literally "about-me-text"

Comment: did you run following commands and restart runserver? `django-admin.py makemessages -l fr` and `django-admin.py compilemessages`

Comment: Wait, Django 1.3? If at all possible, could you isolate these parts in a clean virtualenv with at least 1.9? Just to make sure we're not hitting a bug nobody can remember got fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying a few suggestions by Emile and Melvyn I had luck changing my LANGUAGE_CODE from 'en' to 'en-us' and making the same change in LANGUAGES as well. My updated settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en-us','English'),
    ('fr','French'),
)
```

I missed the issue because I ignored the error shown here [AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute '_info'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816158/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-info) which was telling me 'en' was not a valid LANGUAGE_CODE. I'm not really sure why en-us works over en but for now it has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to do 2 different things at the same time.

1. Translate the text
2. Pass text into the template as a variable

If so, here is the the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code)

```
{% trans about-me-text %}
```

Pass the text in as the variable about-me-text. For more information on how to do this in your view, here is that [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-python-code).

Working off your view:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

def about_me(request):
    output = _('This is the about me block.')
    return render_to_response('about_me.html', {'output':output}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: If I take the quotes off of about-me-text it doesn't generate a msgid in my django.po file for me to translate. I added an example of what my .po file looks like.

Comment: @CodyPollard But, did you compile the messages? So do you have `.mo` files?

Comment: @CodyPollard can you share your view to see what you are trying to load?

Comment: Yes I compiled it after creating the .po and restarted the runserver.

Comment: @Emile yes, added.

Comment: That is the template, what about the view?

Comment: Still no luck, I re-compiled the messages and restarted the server after making the change to view. I will work on recreating this in Django 1.9 as suggested and to see if I can recreate the problem.

Comment: @Emile one thing to mention is I ran into this problem earlier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816158/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-info I fixed it with the solution suggested there but I have a feeling that might have something to do with my translations not showing up.