# Why does my aging Django 1.3.1 site say ''TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/" after migration to a new server?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django v1.3.1 site  on a now-compromised server (used to be on Python v2.7.3). I've been able to reconstruct the bulk of the content via a cache of the old admin site but after re-installing Python and Django on a new server instance (Python v2.7.12), I'm running across the following error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/
admin/login.html
Request Method: GET
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
    admin/login.html
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 138
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
    ['/var/django/mysite',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
     '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
    Server time:    Sun, 15 Oct 2017 02:31:49 +0100
```

The relevant info from trying to load the templates:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/var/django/mysite/templates/admin/login.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
```

Looking on the new machine for /admin/index.html I get:

```
locate admin/login.html
/usr/local/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html
```

On the old machine I get:

```
locate admin/login.html
/root/build/Django/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html
/root/build/Django/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html
/root/build/Django/tests/templates/custom_admin/login.html
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html
```

What have I missed in getting this up and running / how do I resolve this before I start upgrading to the latest Django version?

---

**Edit** - contents of `TEMPLATE_DIRS`:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/var/django/mysite/templates','C:/Users/jon/PycharmProjects/mysite/templates',)
```

I have this set too so I don't think it matters whether `app_dir` is `False` or not(?):

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

Comment: What is the value of `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in your `settings.py` file?

Comment: its seem your `app_dir` var inside `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like my Django install was corrupted (including pip's cache of it). The following sorted it out:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/pip
pip2.7 uninstall django
pip2.7 install django==1.3.1 --no-cache-dir
```

Solved thanks to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017306/pip-and-virtualenv-installing-parts-of-django-in-the-wrong-place).

Comment: In current pip versions you are likely to need `--no-binary Django` also.